# How do you force quit an application in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, iphone

In iOS 6 and below I could double tap the home button, tap and hold an app, and  click the red <kbd>-</kbd> to close an application(s).

In iOS 7 this does not work. How can I restart an app that's exploding without resetting the entire OS?

Comment: FWIW, In my case iTunes was crashing after upgrading from iOS6 to iOS7.  I went into iTunes settings and logged out of my account then logged back in.  That corrected the issue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In iOS 7:

1. Double tap the home button
2. Scroll to the app you want to force quit
3. Flick up on the app's window.

Comment: The window is the key element here. I was concentrating on the app like it used to be done!

Comment: This has been confusing a lot of people. I'm glad you figured it out.

Comment: Yup, the old way was a very small touch target, and also a very similar action to deleting an app which caused confusion.  The new way (which is actually pretty much copied from the now defunct WebOS) makes a distinction between removing the app windows, and the app.  It's also interesting to note that you can use multiple fingers to remove multiple app windows at a time, especially amusing on an iPad.

Answer (score 9):

An alternative method: *(if you're still in the app)*

1. Hold **Power** (until you get the **slide to power off**).
2. Hold **Home** until the app quits.

Comment: Interesting, it's relaunching the app? Do you have some support document that details what exactly this does?

Comment: @deceze It doesn't relaunch it; just force quit - you have to relaunch it yourself. AFAIK, it's extremely similar (if not identical) to the other methods in the way it quits an app. I can't find any official Apple support docs referring to this - a brief search of Apple's KB articles only shows [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5137) which describes the methods given by the other answers. I've known this method for ages since I used it before the days of multitasking!

Comment: When I tried it the app (Safari) just kind of reloaded instead of quitting.

Comment: @deceze Indeed, it does appear to restart Safari **occasionally** (or at least Safari on iOS 7 - how strange), however it works correctly with every other app…

Comment: @deceze This tried and trusted method has never (rarely) failed me since iPhone OS 1.0!

Comment: Notably, this is similar to [the way to force quit an app on the Apple Watch](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/187265/218).

Answer (score 6):

Double tap the home button.

You then get snapshots of the apps that you can scroll to left or right to find the app you want.

You can drag that app up to close it and remove from the display.