# How do I force-quit an individual app on Apple Watch?

Tags: apple-watch

On my iPhone, I can force-quit the active app by double-clicking the home button and swiping the app to the top.

How can I force-quit / terminate the active app on the Apple Watch without restarting the entire device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For watchOS 3 and newer:**

1. Press and hold the Side Button
2. Press and hold the Digital Crown

**For watchOS 2:**

When the app that you would like to terminate is open:

1. Press and hold the Side Button and wait until the shut down screen appear. Then let go of the side button.
2. Press and hold the Side button again until the home screen appears.

Your formerly active app has now been terminated.

PS: The Side Button is the button below the Digital Crown.